# Issue in parsing Json Response in iOS application, getting "=" at the place of ":" in Dictionary

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing, dictionary

I am working on an iOS application and using swift in it. I am calling an Rest api and response is JSON.

Here is my code:

```
{

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: path)! as URL)

        // Set the method to POST
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        do {
            // Set the POST body for the request

            let jsonBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonBody

            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            //            request.addValue("Cookie", forHTTPHeaderField: session_Id)

            let session = URLSession.shared

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

                if let jsonData = data {

                    print("\(data?.debugDescription)")
                    do {

                        print("JSON Response String: \(String.init(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))")

                        let dict:[String:Any] = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String:Any])!


                        print("JSON Response Dictionary: \(dict)")

                        onCompletion(dict, nil)

                    } catch {
                        // report ERROR

                        print("caught: \(error)")

                        onCompletion(nil, error as! NSError)

                    }



                } else {


                    print(error)
                    onCompletion(nil, error as! NSError)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        } catch {
            // Create your personal error


            onCompletion(nil, nil)
        }
    }
```

And This is the response of api:

```
======== - Fetch CC list api request - =============
["userID": "898465844"]
======== - Fetch CC list api request - =============

JSON Response String: "{\"status\":\"success\",\"card_list\":[{\"cardType\":\"Visa\",\"cardholderName\":null,\"expirationMonth\":\"01\",\"expirationYear\":\"2020\",\"cardImage\":\"https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox\",\"cardNumber\":\"411111******1111\",\"token\":\"348nws\"}]}"


JSON Response Dictionary: ["status": success, "card_list": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x1c060f350>(
{
    cardImage = "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/payment_method_logo/visa.png?environment=sandbox";
    cardNumber = "411111******1111";
    cardType = Visa;
    cardholderName = "<null>";
    expirationMonth = 01;
    expirationYear = 2020;
    token = 348nws;
}
)
]
```

After parsing I am getting "=" at the place of ":" in "card_list" array of dictionary.

So I am not able to figure out why I am getting "=" at the place of ":".

Comment: `JSON Response String` is a regular JSON string. `JSON Response Dictionary` is the output of `print`ing a Swift or Objective-C array.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your response is not look like JSON. Its property list or (XML) try to use - `PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from:...)` or some XML parsers